# Dataframe filtering rows by column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a Dataframe `df`

```
       Num1   Num2 
one       1      0
two       3      2
three     5      4
four      7      6
five      9      8
```

I want to filter rows that have value bigger than 3 in Num1 and smaller than 8 in Num2.

I tried this

```
df = df[df['Num1'] > 3 and df['Num2'] < 8]
```

but the error occurred.

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.

so I used

```
df = df[df['Num1'] > 3]
df = df[df['Num2'] < 8]
```

I think the code can be shorter.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 31):

You need add `()` because operator precedence with bit-wise operator `&`:

```
df1 = df[(df['Num1'] > 3) & (df['Num2'] < 8)]
print (df1)
       Num1  Num2
three     5     4
four      7     6
```

Better explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25901335/2901002).

Or if need shortest code use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df.query("Num1 > 3 and Num2 < 8")
print (df1)
       Num1  Num2
three     5     4
four      7     6
```

---

```
df1 = df.query("Num1 > 3 &  Num2 < 8")
print (df1)
       Num1  Num2
three     5     4
four      7     6
```

Comment: if we're going for fewer characters, we could address column names like `df.Num` (given that the name is a valid python variable name, eg alpha numeric, starting with a letter, underscores permitted), too!

Comment: didn't know about `df.query`! Thanks!

Comment: Notice that `df.query` does not seem to work if the column has any special character. It does not work, e.g., for `dash-case` styled columns for the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use the `&` operator:

```
df = df[(df['Num1'] > 3) & (df['Num2'] < 8)]
#                        ^ & operator
```

This is because `and` works on the *truthiness value* of the two operands, whereas the `&` operator can be defined on arbitrary data structures.

The brackets are mandatory here, because `&` binds shorter than `>` and `<`, so without brackets, Python would read the expression as `df['Num1'] > (3 & df['Num2']) < 8`.

Note that you can use the `|` operator as a logical or.