# Pandas boolean indexing error with .drop()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to move away from using chained assignment in Pandas.  While I discovered this behavior trying to update my assignment practices, I don't think it's related to assignment per se.  As shown in the examples below, it seems to be the filtering process itself.  It seems like a bug... but perhaps I'm missing something?

```
df = pd.DataFrame( data = {
                         'acol'  : [1.0, 3.00, 11.0, 31.0, 100.0, 314.0],
                         'bcol' :  [1.0, 3.14, 10.1, 31.4,  81.2, 314.1]
                        })
```

My old method would have been to filter and re-assign, keeping some rows conditionally:

```
In[20]: df[(df.acol > df.bcol) & (df.acol > 10)]

Out[20]:
    acol    bcol
2   11.0    10.1
4   100.0   81.2
```

The new, more responsible me is trying to use the `.drop()` function instead... but the results seem inconsistent :

```
In[21]: df.drop((df.acol <= df.bcol) | (df.acol <= 10), axis=0)
Out[21]: 
    acol    bcol
2   11.0    10.1
3   31.0    31.4
4   100.0   81.2
5   314.0   314.1
```

De Morgan's Theorem says those should give the same result (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

I've checked the docs (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), but this behavior doesn't seem to be mentioned.  I'm aware that there's some ambiguity in dataframe indexing, but by using the bitwise operators, I should be avoiding that ([Pandas boolean DataFrame selection ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901259/pandas-boolean-dataframe-selection-ambiguity)).

What's even more concerning is that if I remove the zeroth entry from each list for the input data, I get different results when using `.drop()` (row 2 disappears)!

I'm using Python 3.6, Pandas 0.20.2

Halp?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `df.index` and then [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
print (df.index[((df.acol <= df.bcol) | (df.acol <= 10))])
Int64Index([0, 1, 3, 5], dtype='int64')

df1 = df.drop(df.index[((df.acol <= df.bcol) | (df.acol <= 10))])
print (df1)
    acol  bcol
2   11.0  10.1
4  100.0  81.2
```

In your code:

```
df.drop((df.acol <= df.bcol) | (df.acol <= 10))
```

is boolean mask converted to `0` and `1`, so first and second row was removed.

```
print ((df.acol <= df.bcol) | (df.acol <= 10))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

---

So in my opinion use `drop` here is a bit overcomplicated solution, better is use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) only:

```
df[(df.acol > df.bcol) & (df.acol > 10)]
```

or alternative solution with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df.query("acol > bcol & acol > 10")
print (df1)
    acol  bcol
2   11.0  10.1
4  100.0  81.2
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the conversion to 0/1, which is happening unbeknownst to the user.  I filed a bug suggesting either a warning, or at least clarification of this point in the documentation.
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16877

Comment: Warning for others like me who thought this could be used to remove duplicate rows in-place with `df.drop(df.index[df.index.duplicated()], inplace=True)`: it doesn't work because by switching from the boolean mask to the labels, you're actually removing *all* rows with that label, not only the duplicates. `pandas.drop` isn't really suited for use with boolean masks in the most general way.

Answer (score 1):

`df.drop()` works with labels, or indexes. If you want to use it with a boolean mask, do

```
df.drop(df.index[(df.acol <= df.bcol) | (df.acol <= 10)])
```

It's also more efficient to include an `inplace=True` argument instead of reassigning.

(As for the why this happens, it's just unexpected behavior as far as I know: you get the same result by passing `[ True,  True, False,  True, False,  True]` as the argument to `.drop()`.)

Comment: The comment by @jezrael clarified this for me: because the booleans get converted to 0 or 1, the 0th and/or 1st rows of the dataframe will get dropped, but no others.  E.g., passing in an `[True, True, True, True, True, True]` will eliminate the 1st row, but leave all others.

I definitely find the behavior unexpected, so I'll file a bug with the pandas developers.